# Android Permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is always denied

Tags: java, android, permissions

I try to check the **permission** on button click and it always gives me **-1**

Here is my `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.natalia.assignment_2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also i have `compileSdkVersion` 28, `minSdkVersion` 22 and `targetSdkVersion` 28.

In my `MainActivity`, I try to check the permissions and it always denied, because it returns **-1**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button buttonLocate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLocate);

    buttonLocate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            askForPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
    });
}

private void askForPermission(String permission) {

    if(MainActivity.this != null) {
        if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // IT ALWAYS COMES TO THIS IF AND SHOWS -1
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + String.valueOf(PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } 
}
```

}

I tried many hours, but nothing helps...what could be a problem here?

Comment: Well did you grant it?

Comment: @TheWanderer In the manifest, or should i do something else?..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 0):

> askForPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");

This is what you had when passing into your method.
Try doing :

```
askForPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
```

This may work. If not, I checked some other articles and everywhere I looked, it wasn't passed in as a String.

Try using this without a String:

```
(PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

Hope it works!